# HMAIL server not receiving mails from localhost

Tags: php, server, xampp, thunderbird, hmail-server

I am using Windows 365 Business Cloud, and i amtrying to setup hmail server on my windows but thunderbird doesn't receive emails, I setup Hmailserver on a windows365  with open ports on inbound and outbound rules for windosws control panel, and I setup PHP with xampp for localhost and connected Thunderbird with "collect@localhost.local" account from Hmail server, I have configured *php.ini like this

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = sender@localhost.local

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = C:/xampp/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t
```

But emails are not coming to the inbox when i use php mail function, what is the cause, If windows365 is nnot accepting it's own email from localhost to localhost, can i change port and let hmail listen elsewhere or no other work around to send and receive only localhost to. localhost mail with php.  my hmail logs looks like this

````
"TCPIP" 10688   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.090"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:25."
"SMTPD" 10688   5   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.106"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T ESMTP"
"TCPIP" 2624    "2021-10-30 05:52:26.090"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:25."
"TCPIP" 4900    "2021-10-30 05:52:26.090"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:587."
"TCPIP" 11648   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.090"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:143."
"TCPIP" 6172    "2021-10-30 05:52:26.090"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:143."
"TCPIP" 8888    "2021-10-30 05:52:26.090"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:587."
"SMTPD" 10688   5   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.106"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org"
"SMTPD" 2624    9   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.106"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T ESMTP"
"IMAPD" 11648   13  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"IMAPD" 6172    7   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"SMTPD" 10688   5   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250-CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T[nl]250-SIZE 20480000[nl]250-AUTH LOGIN[nl]250 HELP"
"SMTPD" 2624    9   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org"
"IMAPD" 11648   13  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 1 CAPABILITY"
"IMAPD" 6172    7   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 1 CAPABILITY"
"SMTPD" 10688   5   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 2624    9   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250-CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T[nl]250-SIZE 20480000[nl]250-AUTH LOGIN[nl]250 HELP"
"IMAPD" 11648   13  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]1 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 6172    7   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]1 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"SMTPD" 10688   5   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
"SMTPD" 2624    9   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"IMAPD" 11648   13  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 2 LOGOUT"
"IMAPD" 6172    7   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 2 LOGOUT"
"SMTPD" 2624    9   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
"IMAPD" 11648   13  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * BYE Have a nice day[nl]2 OK Logout completed"
"IMAPD" 6172    7   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.121"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * BYE Have a nice day[nl]2 OK Logout completed"
"SMTPD" 8888    8   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.137"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T ESMTP"
"SMTPD" 8888    8   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.137"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org"
"SMTPD" 8888    8   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.137"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250-CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T[nl]250-SIZE 20480000[nl]250-AUTH LOGIN[nl]250 HELP"
"SMTPD" 8888    8   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.137"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 8888    8   "2021-10-30 05:52:26.137"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
"SMTPD" 4900    10  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.153"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T ESMTP"
"SMTPD" 4900    10  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.153"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org"
"SMTPD" 4900    10  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.153"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250-CPC-JOSIE-RC-0T[nl]250-SIZE 20480000[nl]250-AUTH LOGIN[nl]250 HELP"
"SMTPD" 4900    10  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.153"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 4900    10  "2021-10-30 05:52:26.153"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
"TCPIP" 11648   "2021-10-30 05:52:39.528"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:143."
"IMAPD" 11648   14  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.528"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"IMAPD" 7248    14  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.528"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 28 capability"
"IMAPD" 7248    14  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.528"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]28 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 4900    14  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.528"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 30 login "collect@localhost.local" ***"
"IMAPD" 4900    14  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.544"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 30 OK LOGIN completed"
"TCPIP" 11648   "2021-10-30 05:52:39.840"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:143."
"IMAPD" 11648   15  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.872"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"IMAPD" 11648   14  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.934"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 31 logout"
"IMAPD" 11648   14  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.970"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * BYE Have a nice day[nl]31 OK Logout completed"
"IMAPD" 7248    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.981"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 81 capability"
"IMAPD" 7248    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:39.997"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]81 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.184"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 83 login "collect@localhost.local" ***"
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 83 OK LOGIN completed"
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 84 capability"
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]84 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 85 namespace"
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * NAMESPACE (("" ".")) NIL (("#Public" "."))[nl]85 OK namespace command complete"
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 86 list "" "*""
"IMAPD" 8996    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"[nl]86 OK LIST completed"
"IMAPD" 4900    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 87 lsub "" "*""
"IMAPD" 4900    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX""
"IMAPD" 4900    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.200"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 87 OK LSUB completed"
"IMAPD" 11648   15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.216"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 88 list "" "#Public*""
"IMAPD" 11648   15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.216"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 88 OK LIST completed"
"IMAPD" 8888    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.216"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 89 lsub "" "#Public*""
"IMAPD" 8888    15  "2021-10-30 05:52:40.216"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: " ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed this by checking sendmail.ini and changing the smtp_server to localhost and it's working fine.

```
[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=localhost
```